# R: Split dataframe into list by group and row iteration

Tags: r, list, split

I have a dataframe like so:

```
set.seed(34)
startingframe <-  data.frame(
  group1=factor(rep(c("a","b"),each=3,times=1)),
  time=rep(1:3,each=1,times=2),
  othercolumn=rnorm(1:6)
)
```

...which I am trying to manipulate into a list that splits by group and each 'iteration' of the `time` column, results looking like so:

```
 $a1
  group1 time othercolumn
1      a    1    -0.13889

$a2
  group1 time othercolumn
1      a    1   -0.138890
2      a    2    1.199813

$a3
  group1 time othercolumn
1      a    1  -0.1388900
2      a    2   1.1998129
3      a    3  -0.7477224

$b1
  group1 time othercolumn
4      b    1  -0.5752482

$b2
  group1 time othercolumn
4      b    1  -0.5752482
5      b    2  -0.2635815

$b3
  group1 time othercolumn
4      b    1  -0.5752482
5      b    2  -0.2635815
6      b    3  -0.4554921
```

I think I just need the iteration bit incorporated into this code:

```
split_list <- split(startingframe,list(startingframe$group1,startingframe$time))
```

EDIT: I may have oversimplified the original problem, but the real dataset has additional columns that would need to be brought through in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `head` for every number in the sequence `1:nrow(x)`, for each sub-group `x` of your data

```
out <- lapply(split(df, df$group1), function(x) lapply(1:nrow(x), head, x = x))
out <- unlist(out, recursive = F)

out
# $`a1`
#    group1 time
# 1:      a    1
# 
# $a2
#    group1 time
# 1:      a    1
# 2:      a    2
# 
# $a3
#    group1 time
# 1:      a    1
# 2:      a    2
# 3:      a    3
# 
# $b1
#    group1 time
# 1:      b    1
# 
# $b2
#    group1 time
# 1:      b    1
# 2:      b    2
# 
# $b3
#    group1 time
# 1:      b    1
# 2:      b    2
# 3:      b    3
```

You might not need to create a list of all these dataframes though, you could just create a list of indices and use them as needed.

```
inds <- 
  lapply(split(seq(nrow(df)), df$group1), function(x) 
    lapply(1:length(x), function(y) x[seq(y)]))

inds
# $`a`
# $`a`[[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# $`a`[[2]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $`a`[[3]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# 
# $b
# $b[[1]]
# [1] 4
# 
# $b[[2]]
# [1] 4 5
# 
# $b[[3]]
# [1] 4 5 6

df[inds$b[[2]]]
#    group1 time
# 1:      b    1
# 2:      b    2
```

Comment: I guess the issue here is that it creates a list of lists?

Comment: You can use `unlist` if you want it as a single list of data frames. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not splitting here, but generating the desired output.

```
genlist = function(l,t){return((data.frame(group1=rep(x = l,times=t),time=seq(from=1,to = t,by = 1))))}

mapply(genlist,startingframe$group1,startingframe$time,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Comment: Is there a way that this would work if we wanted to bring through additional columns in the table?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be using `lapply` inside another `lapply`

```
lapply(levels(startingframe$group1), function(group) {
  df = startingframe[startingframe$group1 == group, ]
  lapply(df$time, function(time) {
    df[df$time %in% 1:time, ]
  })
})

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
  group1 time
1      a    1

[[1]][[2]]
  group1 time
1      a    1
2      a    2

[[1]][[3]]
  group1 time
1      a    1
2      a    2
3      a    3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
  group1 time
4      b    1

[[2]][[2]]
  group1 time
4      b    1
5      b    2

[[2]][[3]]
  group1 time
4      b    1
5      b    2
6      b    3
```