# r split dataframe into list by iterative numeric filter

Tags: r, split, lapply

I am looking for a lapply/split solution (or whatever works) for the following output:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(34)
startingframe <-  data.frame(
  time=rep(1:5,each=1,times=1),
  othercolumn=rnorm(1:5)
)

startingframeout1 <- startingframe %>% dplyr::filter(time >= 1)
startingframeout2 <- startingframe %>% dplyr::filter(time >= 2)
startingframeout3 <- startingframe %>% dplyr::filter(time >= 3)
startingframelist <- list(startingframeout1, startingframeout2, startingframeout3)
startingframelist


[[1]]
  time  othercolumn
1    1  0.670620044
2    2 -0.849014621
3    3  1.066804504
4    4 -0.007460534
5    5 -0.402880091

[[2]]
  time  othercolumn
1    2 -0.849014621
2    3  1.066804504
3    4 -0.007460534
4    5 -0.402880091

[[3]]
  time  othercolumn
1    3  1.066804504
2    4 -0.007460534
3    5 -0.402880091
```

In words, I am looking to turn `startingframe` into a list of dataframes that satisfies the numeric filter. Ideally I would feed a filter range into a function eg. `timefilter <- c(1:3)` There is a similar but not 100% applicable solution here: [R: Split dataframe into list by group and row iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598701/r-split-dataframe-into-list-by-group-and-row-iteration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility to solve this is using `lapply()` with an appropriate function like this:

```
lapply(1:5, function(x) {startingframe %>% filter(time >= x)})
```